Silverman AEC Exercise 7.4
The following problem in chapter 7 of Silverman's book has been bothering me:

Here's my progress:
I first tried to solve it in the $\text{char}(k) \ne 2,3$ case, wherein we can assume the equation is $y^2=x^3+Ax+B.$ and is minimal, so that $\nu(\Delta)<12$ or $\nu(c_4)<4.$ Here, $3\nu(x(P)) = 2\nu(y(P))$ from the equation as $n>1$ and $A,B \in R.$ So if $P, Q \in E_n(K),$ then $$x(P+Q)=m^2-x(P)-x(Q), \text{ where }m=\frac{y(P)-y(Q)}{x(P)-x(Q)}.$$
If we assume $\nu(x(P)) < \nu(x(Q)),$ then it is easy to conclude $\nu(m)=\nu(x(P))/2$ and so $\nu(x(P+Q))=\nu(x(P)) \le -2n.$
But if $\nu(x(P)) = \nu(x(Q)),$ I am not sure how to proceed.
Is this just some similar $\nu$ analysis, or are there any clever ideas involved? I also can't figure out how to use the minimality condition, which does seem essential.
P.S. These $E_0, E_1$ are different from the ones in the text, right? For reference, $E_0(K)= \{P \in E(K):\widetilde P \in \widetilde E_{ns}(k)\},$ and
$E_1(K)= \{P \in E(K):\widetilde P =0\}$ in the text. The quotient $E_0/E_1 \cong \widetilde E_{ns}(k) \cong k^+$ holds for additive reduction too.

These are in fact the same $E_0$, $E_1$ as in the text. Think carefully about how the reduction map is defined in Section VII.2. Probably the easiest way to proceed for the exercise is to use the formal group law. Remember that the formal group law is set up to use coordinates in the $XZ$-plane, so that $O$ lies at the origin, which necessitates a change of variables from the standard $XY$-plane Weierstrass equation; see also Proposition 2.2.
